# Updating Simple Preferential Attachment Model in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

There is a model in NetLogo based on simple preferential attachment. Agents create links thusly:

```
to go
  if count turtles > num-nodes [ stop ]
  let partner one-of [both-ends] of one-of links
  create-turtles 1 [
    set color red
    move-to partner
    fd 1
    create-link-with partner
  ]
  layout
  tick
end
```

In this model, a node's chance of being selected is directly proportional to the number of connections it already has. I want to edit this code so that there is  a variable, prestige, which also determines the probability that a node will be selected. I understand that I need to create a variable for turtles called prestige, but I'm stuck on how to make it so that the probability that a link will be created is also proportional to the amount of prestige a turtle has.

Comment: see Lottery Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library

Comment: ...or the Rnd Example, in the Extensions Examples section of the library, for an easier way to achieve the same thing using the `rnd` extension.